# How to polyfill onmouseenter/onmouseleave in Blazor 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor

Events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are not supported in Blazor, .NET 6. A [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/40829) with their implementation has been merged, but is currently not part of a stable version.

How can these events be used in .NET 6?

Comment: You need JSInterop for that. You can call some method using js on mouseenter and then call .net method from js.

Comment: Link that explains how to handle custom events which should work for you  - https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2021/05/04/aspnetcore6-07-custom-event-arguments.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a static class named `EventHandlers`, which can be used to define built-in events.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;

namespace YourApp.Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a polyfill until https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/40829
    /// gets released in a stable version.
    /// </summary>
    [EventHandler("onmouseleave", typeof(MouseEventArgs), true, true)]
    [EventHandler("onmouseenter", typeof(MouseEventArgs), true, true)]
    public static class EventHandlers
    {
    }
}
```

Source: [Blazor 3.1 nested onmouseover events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151537/628637)