# How to use onmouseenter with Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

neither `<img onmouseenter="@ClickTest()">` nor `<img @onmouseenter="ClickTest">` works.

where the called function is this:

```
    void ClickTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Image clicked");
    }
```

How to do that correctly?

Comment: May I know which Blazor you are used? WASM or Server app? And what is the version?

Comment: @YongShun - that seems hardly relevant for en event question.

Comment: you seems need to create a static class named `EventHandlers`. refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886638/how-to-polyfill-onmouseenter-onmouseleave-in-blazor-6)

Comment: Probably relate to this issue: [Blazor add support for the onmouseenter and onmouseleave dom events in components](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13104)

Comment: @HH, the reason why asking the version used is as the link I shared in previous comment.

Comment: That is very (very) ancient.